# After chroot and chdir, corresponding execv fails, returning EACCESS to parent process

Tags: c, linux, chroot

I am trying to sandbox a utility in C. I followed the below steps:

1. Created the sandbox resources `file,directory, sharpoint` for that utility under folder `/sandbox/myutil`.
2. From "c" code, called `chdir("/sandbox/myutil")`, `chroot("/")`.
3. Ensured that utility executable is available at `/sandbox/myutil/bin/util.bin`, and all the dependency files are available under `/sandbox/myutil`.
4. Called utility `bin/util.bin` by `execve("/bin/util.bin",arg, env);`

However, `/bin/util.bin` is not executing as expected, the process received the signal 18 and returns code 13 "EACCESS".

However, if instead of calling `chroot()`, `chdir()` and `execve()` from c code, I use the commands `chroot /sandbox/myutil /bin/util.bin` executed from a shell, it works fine.

I am using kernel 2.6.17.

Comment: sorry it was typo, used "chroot ("/sandbox/myutil"), chdir ("/")."